# How to stop smoke from lingering around

Tags: smoke-simulation, error

I am currently trying to make an explosion with mantaflow. Everything is just working fine except the fact that the smoke just keeps lingering over the particle emitter/smoke inflow (from frame 160 onward), even though the last particles where gone around frame 65... And yeah, I've set the flow source to my particle system...
Also tried this with blender 2.83.2 and 2.83.3 with no differences in baking behavior.
Don't know if this is a bug or I'm just stupid...

[image: Explosion simulation]

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

After a bit of thinking i solved the problems myself... I'm assuming that there was some interference with the collider plane and the emitter... I moved the emitter a little bit higher, away from the plane, which had a collision (particles) and a smoke collider physic simulation active...